# Need help with pooling in Memcached

Tags: java, memcached, connection-pooling, object-pooling, spymemcached

I have a web application running on multiple servers. And I am planning to implement Memcached into this app with spymemcached as the client.
I have created a pool of memcached clients. But I am not sure if the client being borrowed from the pool would be able to create more than one connection to the memcached server.

I want to have a pool of connections that the client from the client pool could use.
If this method is fine, then how should I proceed with the implementation? Or else what should be the best method?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about what your asking here. Currently Spymemcached only creates one connection to each server. Do you want to be able to create multiple connections to each server from a single MemcachedClient object? If you do are you asking how to implement this inside Spymemcached?

Comment: I was a bit confused because of which u got confused. I was planning to use the X number of MemcachedClient object to use Y number of connections. But found out that is not possible/feasible. Now instead I will be using X (arnd 40) number of MemcachedClient object on 10 servers. So, I can have at max 400 connections to the server. I was confused because I thought that one MemcachedClient object could connect to memcached server via more than one connection

Comment: It's unclear what problem you're trying to solve by doing this.  What problem are you measuring by only having one connection that you think having multiple would solve?

Comment: I thought that if its possible that one client could have more than one connection, then lesser no of clients needs to be created. This way lesser number of threads would be running on my tomcat server(since each client is basically a thread). But finally found out that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

> But I am not sure if the client being borrowed from the pool would be able to create more than one connection to the memcached server.

No.

> I want to have a pool of connections that the client from the client pool could use. If this method is fine, then how should I proceed with the implementation? Or else what should be the best method?

You can use [commons-pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/) as a pooling framework around spy.memcached. See [this](https://github.com/moresandeep/P4M) for implementation.

Comment: Thanks @sandeep. I have already implemented the pooling framework last month. P4M helped me a lot in understanding the concepts and implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Some people use DBCP for pooling the connections. You can look at **3levelmemcache** project as an example at **github** it has pooling configured via Spring.